# How to Check a (Canadian) SIN is a genuine SIN?

Tags: validation

A Canadian SIN is equivalent to American SSN.

I am **not** asking for the algorithm to check if any given 9-digit number passes the validation of the [Luhn validation](http://www.ryerson.ca/JavaScript/lectures/forms/textValidation/sinProject.html).

The problem I have is some users are smart enough to generate a fake SIN that can pass the above validation, but the SIN would not exist in the government database.

Therefore, what I am asking is how I can check the given SIN number is genuine and actually issued by the Canadian Government.  Is there any database/services you can get or is there any special algorithm you use to verify this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If there were an algorithm, it could be used to generate a fake SIN.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: There is an algorithm and it is being used to generate fake SIN.  That is why I am asking if there is alternative data source to validate that.

Comment: @Paul - the larger concern would be identity theft, I'd think.

Comment: Really? Asking for SINs on the internet? I feel bad for the people dumb enough to enter them.

Comment: @Ryan, what Paul is saying is that if there were an alternative source to validate fake SINs, the fakers would use that and only generate valid, unfake SINs.

Comment: @Ryan, you specifically asked for "special algorithm", and I'm explaining why such a special algorithm can't possibly exist, if by "special", you mean one that can be used to verify a SIN and can't be used to figure out a spoof SIN.

Comment: @Dour High Arch: Thanks for the comments.  I understand such algorithm wouldn't exist otherwise fakers would use that to generate fake SINs as well.   Therefore, I am hoping to find out if there is such thing as @Thorarin in the Netherlands that would provide the data services to restricted agents.

Comment: @Ryan, @Thorarin's service cannot possibly work for the reason we have explained. You will have to use an authentication method other than SSNs.

Comment: @Dour High Arch: Anyways, it seems like alternative data services or algorithm is not an option.  I guess I will ask our business unit to just keep a list of all the fake SINs and add more to the list on a case by case basis.   Then this internal fake SIN list will be our references at least for this company.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems like data that's extremely unlikely to be made public. You will probably need to be a government agency to see a list of SINs.

Also, as Paul noted above, any algorithm which verifies whether a SIN is a possible candidate can also be used to manufacture SINs that aren't legitimate through brute force.

Comment: A service wouldn't necessarily have to expose a SIN to the public in order to validate that it exists.  However, even if such a service existed, access to it would still probably have to be controlled.

Comment: @wcm: If such a service existed, all you'd have to do is run the algorithm Paul mentioned, querying each SIN in turn and accreting a list of the valid ones. Since there's only 1 billion possible SINs with 9 digits, of which at least some must not be legal SINs.

Answer (score 2):

As an added note to John and Paul's answers. If there is an algorithm to generate SIN's and a database of assigned SIN's you could combine the two to search through and find a real SIN in fairly short order allowing you to gather a list of all active SIN's. In a pseudo code manner you could use ...

```
foreach(SIN in SINGenerator)
{
    if(govtdatabase.verify(SIN) == true)
    { store into file as valid SIN }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Having worked with SINs before I do know that there's some correlation to the beginning 3 numbers of the SIN and the person's age.  As well, there are some validation rules much like credit card numbers (which you've noted.)

With that said **Why are you using SIN numbers?** It is an extremely vital piece of information - If you have someone's SIN number you effectively are them - and should under no circumstances be used by anyone except for government related purposes!

Secondly if you have a legitimate usage of SIN numbers, are you familiar with [PIPEDA](http://www.priv.gc.ca/legislation/02_06_01_e.cfm)?  If not you should be!

Comment: I am working in a project for a financial institution.  The client has some fake SINs slipped through the cracks and now they want to be able to identify and validate against the fake SINs that are not issued by the government.

Comment: Have you asked the financial institution how they validate the SINs?  They ought to know if how they're using the information...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Canada, but here in the Netherlands such webservices are only available to government related organisations, insurance companies, healthcare providers, etc.

I'm actually working with such a service at the moment. It's not just number validation. It allows retrieval of name, address, date of birth and so on based on the number.

It's unlikely something like that will be public. **[See also this privacy FAQ](http://www.priv.gc.ca/fs-fi/02_05_d_02_e.cfm)**. Read it. It also contains information on valid uses for SINs.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for exits in secured functioning;
your client must be registered to represent a client with the Taxation Corporation CRA(Canada) or Irs(USA). You client then will have have access to the government's site. Enter sin on request and it will tell you (1) if valid, (2) if you have do not have right to information on the sin--indirectly verifying it,or (3) access if your represent a client is now on file for the sin in question.

Please note this is not the intended use for the government site and as such may invoke their wrath, but will work.